# how to loop through cells with same value in a column until last cell

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I want to loop through a list and fill a template with it in batches of related items but I can't seem to figure out how to do it. I have been able to loop through all the data but not in group of related items.

I have searched online for a solution but everyone is looping through all the rows but not grouped as shown in the sample  below.

sample data

| SN | DATE | AMOUNT | COURSE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | date1 | amount1 | ABC |
| 1 | date1 | amount1 | ABC |
| 1 | date1 | amount1 | ABC |
| 2 | date2 | amount2 | XYZ |
| 2 | date2 | amount2 | XYZ |
| 3 | date3 | amount3 | ACC |
| 3 | date3 | amount3 | ACC |
| 3 | date3 | amount3 | ACC |

The expected output should look like the following:

```
    <ENTRY><ABC>
    <COURSE> ABC </COURSE>
    <Date> date1 </DATE> <AMOUNT> Amount1 </AMOUNT>
    <Date> date1 </DATE> <AMOUNT> Amount1 </AMOUNT>
    <Date> date1 </DATE> <AMOUNT> Amount1 </AMOUNT>
    </ENTRY>
    
    <ENTRY><XYZ>
    <COURSE> XYZ </COURSE>
    <Date> date2 </DATE> <AMOUNT> Amount2 </AMOUNT>
    <Date> date2 </DATE> <AMOUNT> Amount2 </AMOUNT>
    </ENTRY>

    <ENTRY><ACC>
    <COURSE> ACC </COURSE>
    <Date> date3 </DATE> <AMOUNT> Amount3 </AMOUNT>
    <Date> date3 </DATE> <AMOUNT> Amount3 </AMOUNT>
    <Date> date3 </DATE> <AMOUNT> Amount3 </AMOUNT>
    </ENTRY>
    AND SO ON.....
```

Please let me know if there's need for further clarification.

I am not good at VBA, I am just trying to simplify my work.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Compare each row to previous row and next row to determine if start or end of group.

```vb
Sub macro1()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim r As Long, c As Long, lastrow As Long
    Dim xml As String, tag As String, total As Double
  
    Set ws = Sheet1
    With ws
        lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        For r = 2 To lastrow
            If .Cells(r, 1) <> .Cells(r - 1, 1) Then
                tag = .Cells(1, 4) & ">"
                xml = xml & "<ENTRY>" & vbLf & _
                "<" & tag & .Cells(r, 4) & "</" & tag & vbLf
                total = 0
            End If
      
            For c = 2 To 3
                tag = .Cells(1, c) & ">"
                xml = xml & "<" & tag & _
                .Cells(r, c) & "</" & tag
            Next
            xml = xml & vbLf
            
            total = total + .Cells(r, 3).Value2 ' amount
            If .Cells(r + 1, 1) <> .Cells(r, 1) Then
                xml = xml & "<Total>" & Format(total, "0.00") & "</Total>" & _
                vbLf & "</ENTRY>" & vbLf
            End If
        Next
    End With
    xml = "<DATA>" & vbLf & xml & "</DATA>"
    
    ' output text file
    Const XMLFILE = "output.xml"
    Dim FSO As Object, ts As Object, filename As String
    Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FilesystemObject")
    filename = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & XMLFILE
    Set ts = FSO.createtextfile(filename, overwrite:=True, Unicode:=True)
    ts.write xml
    ts.Close
    
    MsgBox "Done see " & filename, vbInformation
    Shell "Notepad.exe " & filename, 1
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, I am giving it a try already, I will get back as soon as it's done. Thank you so much

Comment: Thanks you, it's perfect. Just the way I wanted it. Thank you so much.

Comment: I just want ask if it's possible to add total to each group. Thank you.

Comment: @Olatunde see update

Comment: I have checked the update but don't understand a thing. Looking forward to hearing from you. Thank you.

Comment: @Olatunde every ENTRY now have a `<Total> some number </Total>` line.

Comment: I am still working on the project, please, is it possible to add the company name to the <ENTRY> tag? Thanks so much.

Comment: @olatunde Do you mean like `<ENTRY name="name">` which column holds the value ?

Comment: Sorry, I mean the course column (column4) holds the value, the output should look like <ENTRY><ABC>. Thanks so much

Comment: @olatunde Course is in tag `<COURSE> ABC </COURSE>` . A single tag `<ABC>` would be invalid XML.

Comment: Ok, I got it, thanks. You're well appreciated.